# WinSCP | Tabbing through file list after upgrade

Tags: windows, ftp, gui, winscp

Before the most recent upgrade (April 2019) I was able to type the first letter of a file name and the file would be "pre-selected" / "highlighted" in the file list. If I repeated to press the same letter, the next file in alphabetical order beginning with that letter would be "pre-selected" ...

After the upgrade, I have to press the letter and then keep pressing `tab` in order to produce the same effect.

I am wondering if anyone knows what I can do to revert this functionality?

(I have since learned this feature is referred to as *"incremental search"*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible since WinSCP 5.15.3 via a hidden configuration option (as I do not think that new users will actually be interested in this).

Run WinSCP once like:

```
winscp.exe /rawconfig Interface\PanelSearch=-1
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a hidden option; it's *exactly* what I needed as the other Incremental Search options are all counterproductive to my workflow and break decades of behavior expected with Windows file browser interfaces.